# rename of file extension doesnt work unix

Tags: unix, file-extension, file-rename

I have two issues:

1)

Im using a code like below to create a logfile using rename functionality:
I have a filename. Incase of error, i need to create a log file with err.

suppose the $fileName is "test.tmp":

```
echo ' l_error_msg' >> $UPLOAD/output/$fileName.err
```

This creates a file named "test.tmp.err".

Hence i tried the below to create a file "test.err":

```
echo ' l_error_msg' >> $UPLOAD/output/${$fileName%.*}.err
```

But this does not work.

2)
I'm moving and renaming using two steps as below. How could i combine and do it effectively?

```
mv -f $UPLOAD/input/* $UPLOAD/output
mv -f $UPLOAD/output/* ${$fileName%.*}.err
```

Note: There will be only one file in the input folder at any point of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as below.

Q 1)  creation of a file "test.err":

```
echo ' l_error_msg' >> $UPLOAD/output/${fileName%.*}.err
```

Q 2) Renaming file

```
mv -f $UPLOAD/input/* $UPLOAD/output/${fileName%.*}.err
```

Answer (score 1):

I Rename file extension files with this command:

```
$ sudo find . -name '*.EXTENSION_OLD' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.EXTENSION_OLD}.EXTENSION_NEW"' {} \;
```